# How to enable mouse acceleration in 14.04?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 14.04

I'm trying to figure out how to enable mouse acceleration in Ubuntu 14.04.

I have an XPS 15 9530, which has a built-in touch-pad (which appears to be recognised, as seen in the screenshot below), but I also have a Microsoft Touch Arc mouse, which works, but doesn't have any acceleration, meaning it's very slow to use.

[image]

Is there some way I can enable acceleration?

Comment: Here is a guide: http://blog.repa.info/2013/06/14/how-to-disable-mouse-acceleration-in-ubuntu-or-any-other-linux/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use below command for that purpose

```
xset m 50 1
```

Where m stands for setting the "mouse" and the first integer represents the "acceleration", and the second represents the "threshold".

The  acceleration  can be specified as an integer, or as a simple fraction, but the threshold is just an integer.

The pointer will go `acceleration` times as fast when the device travels more than `threshold` mickeys in 10 ms, including a  small transition range.

For more information, you can refer to [the xset manual](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xset.1.html).

Comment: Thank you. I found 50 to be a bit too high, but somewhere between 3 and 5 works for me :)