# How do I make a Lenovo (ALPS?) touchpad faster than system allows?

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, lenovo

Running 16.04 on new Lenovo X1. Apparently it has a high-definition ALPS touchpad which makes it incredibly slow, even with the highest setting through "System Settings>Mouse and Touchpad".

I installed dconf-editor (very handy tool) but the speed value is already maxed out. All other mouse-features work, but the slowness issue renders the touchpad nigh unusable. Aargh, first *new* computer in years.

To clarify: Accelleration works fine, it's the slow, exact movements (like drawing, constricting a sketch in FreeCAD) that require me to move across the entire pad, lift, and move again...

Would a different distro (Debian?) or window-manager (Xfce?) make any difference? or switch back to 14.04? (used to run Debian 15 years ago...)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command:

> xset m 50 1

Where `m` stands for setting the **mouse** and the `first integer` represents the **acceleration**  and the `second` represents the **threshold**.

check this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/450672/464430) for more information.