# How do I disable mouse acceleration in ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS?

Tags: 22.04

how do I disable the mouse acceleration? In widows I could easily disable it in the mouse settings but in ubuntu I don't see an option for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Mouse Acceleration and Increase Mouse Sensitivity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996100/disable-mouse-acceleration-and-increase-mouse-sensitivity)

Answer (score 0):

run this in terminal. works like a charm.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse accel-profile flat
```